# Как реализовать сбор данных из других сайтов?

Tags: javascript

Всем добрый день. У меня появилась идея для сайта и чтобы ее реализовать нужно из других сайтов брать данные и показывать на сайте самые выгодные варианты. Сверстать сайт смогу, но как именно сделать функционал не знаю. Подскажите пожалуйста что делать и тд. Умею в html, css, js.

Comment: почитай про парсеры

Comment: "Умею в html, css, js." Node.js в руки и вперед. А возможно и не стоит реализовывать вам такую идею

Comment: Почему не стоит?)